# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-serve'

Tags: node.js, gulp, bootstrap-4, ubuntu-16.04

Ran the following commands...

```
sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-serve -globally
```

into the directory where gulpfile.js lives. Whenever I run `sudo gulp`, I receive the following error...

```
module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-serve'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/bs4/gulpfile.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` with `rm -r node_modules` then try an `npm install`

Comment: What is the output when you try to run it without sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove node_modules then install it without sudo:

```
npm i --save-dev gulp-serve
```